# KodKod Unbound relation Error

Tags: alloy

I have this problem while testing my KodKod program where he tells me that a relation is Unbounded while when I print : "bound.relations()" to see the bounded relations I find that in fact it is bounded.
If you have any ideas i'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell what's going on without a minimal working example.  Printing bound.relations() won't help diagnose the problem:  this will only show the names of the relations that are bound.  That is, it is possible that a relation called 'R' is bound but a different relation called 'R', which is not bound, is used in the formula.  To see if a specific relation object is bound, you'll need to test for its presence via `bound.relations().contains(r)', where r is a reference to the relation.

Comment: In fact I tested with `bound.relations().contains(r)' and returns true, but I still got the same Error. I have rewrote my program to make sure I'm bounding the right relations. Till now what I've understood is that the relation is in contact with the instence of the object, so I had to make sure I am bounding the relation for the right instence !! Idk if I am being clear